# Passing and handle 2D Array from Ajax to Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I passing an array from Jquery(post) to php like:

```
[["a","b","c"],["aa:","bb","cc"]]
```

How to extract this array in php?
My code is:

**UPDATE**

```
 $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
 print_r($data);
```

This code return :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => as
            [1] => as
            [2] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => asas :
            [1] => as
            [2] => text
        )

)
```

Comment: What are you getting on `$data`?

Comment: $data = $_POST['data'];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing an array. You can tackle this two different ways

1) encode everything in JSON and pass it to php.

2) take everything that you need from the form and serialize it. Then explode the serialized data in your language of choice.

Passing arrays will not work the way you think it will. So it's best to just serialize the data and then do what you need. Using loops is a waste of time and CPU resources that could slow down the users experience.

Comment: Did this comment help solve your situation? Please select the best answer to award.